# How to fill dropdown list statically in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to fill dropdown list statically(Hardcoded)

I have 2 items

Text="Active" value="A"

Text="InActive" value="I"

and above values saved into database

Thanks,

Comment: Statically? From DB? what is it? BTW, you can always use pure html for static dropdowns. <select><option value="A">Active</option> ... </select>

Comment: our best friend google will help you a lot

Comment: You are a fool if you it any other way than @UmairP said.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this all in a view, the code would look like this:

```
@{
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("Active", "A");
        dictionary.Add("InActive", "I");
        SelectList list = new SelectList(dictionary, "value", "key");
}
@Html.DropDownList("name", list)
```

Also if you wanted to add a blank, it would look like this:

```
@{
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("", "");
        dictionary.Add("Active", "A");
        dictionary.Add("InActive", "I");
        SelectList list = new SelectList(dictionary, "value", "key");
}
@Html.DropDownList("name", list)
```

And if you wanted to have a particular item selected, it would look like this:

```
@{
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("", "");
        dictionary.Add("Active", "A");
        dictionary.Add("InActive", "I");
        SelectList list = new SelectList(dictionary, "value", "key", "I");
}
@Html.DropDownList("name", list)
```

Notice I changed the `SelectList` line adding a `"I"` parameter, this corresponds to the 'InActice' value causing it to be selected on page load.

This code would generate this in HTML:

```
<select id="name" name="name">
    <option value="A">Active</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="I">InActive</option>
</select>
```

So if this is going to be static you can just use this. You can remove the `selected="selected"` if needed.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "above values saved into database", do you have a model to go with these items? If you edit your question and add some examples of what your trying to do I can help you better.

Comment: Since it was tagged MVC3 I figured I would show how to do it using the HTML helper and Razor syntax. Although normally I would have the code in the controller.

Comment: Woah! it is like killing a bee with a tactical nuke :)