# How to make rows per page value as dynamic one in MVC3 Web Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

> Hi ..,
>
> Can anyone tell me the solution for assigning Dropdown selected value as rowsperpage value in MVC3 WebGrid. how can i do this. Any help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int rowsperpage = 20)
{
    // Logic to take and skip whatever
}
```

In your view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    <select id="rowsperpage" name="rowsperpage">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

To give you a better idea of creating drop down lists with the html helper, see [How to fill dropdown list statically in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10911738/985284)